How to add global middleware user-permissions plugin Strapi v5
Breaking change from v4. Extending plugin beyond content-types seems unavailable in Strapi v5, and only adding modifications to functionality in strapi-server.ts seems available. https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/plugins-extension
I want to create a middleware that works for all routes in the user-permission plugin. how can I do so? I've tried
export default (plugin) => {
  plugin.middlewares = {
    ...plugin.middlewares,
    testMiddleware: async (ctx, next) => {
      console.log('your custom logic 1', ctx);
      await next();
    },
  };
};

doesn't seem possible to just add a middleware function to the middlewares object, unfortunately.
